# TeamsFx - How to change content URL in generated manifest

Tags: microsoft-teams

The installer and manifest.json file generated by TeamsFx automatically points to the `/index.html#/tab` path. How can we change the default path?

We can obviously manually update the manifest file in the generate zip file but this is read only and gets over written every time a new installer is generated.

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/blob/main/msteams-platform/toolkit/TeamsFx-manifest-preview.md
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/blob/main/msteams-platform/toolkit/TeamsFx-multi-env.md
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: yes the link resolves my issue. The files that needed modification was manifest.local.template.json